# Partial matching with userInput in Vespa

Tags: vespa

I'm trying to get partial matching with userInput().

With a document title "toucan", I tried:

- "toucan" (works)
- "touca" (no results)
- "touca*" (no results)

The query: `([{"prefix":true}]userInput(@query)))`

The schema:

```
fieldset default {
  fields: title, content
}

field title type string {
  indexing: index | summary
}

field content type string {
  indexing: index | summary
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix matching requires making the field attribute, not index.
See https://docs.vespa.ai/en/text-matching-ranking.html#prefix-match

Answer (score 0):

Using attribute rather than index works indeed:

With a document title "toucan":

```
"toucan" (works)
"touca" (no results)
"touca*" (works)
```

The query: `([{"prefix":true}]userInput(@query)))`

The schema:

```
fieldset default {
  fields: title, content
}

field title type string {
  indexing: attribute | summary
}

field content type string {
  indexing: index | summary
}
```

But:

- bm25 and other text tricks cannot be applied anymore on field "title". For instance "Toucan blue" cannot be found with "blue"
- It does not work with attributes of type array

Is the best solution to duplicate those fields, and use them both in a fieldset to get prefix (attribute type) and full text (index type)?

Answer (score 0):

We can also use [N-Gram](https://docs.vespa.ai/en/text-matching-ranking.html#n-gram-match) and keep the field as an index.

With a document title "toucan":

```
"toucan" (works)
"touca" (works
"ouca" (works)
```

The query: `(userInput(@query))`

The schema:

```
fieldset default {
  fields: title, content
}

field title type string {
  indexing: index | summary
  match {
    gram
    gram-size: 2 ## the smaller, the most costly in index size
  }
}

field content type string {
  indexing: index | summary
}
```

[image: Search and suggestions with N-Gram and partial keywords]